# How to query depending on relation in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

- I have a table *contracts* that is related to *services* table.
- A contract may have multiple services.
- A service may have a device associated (through the device_id fk).

I need to have a list of contract_id and

1. YES: In case there is at least one service that has a device associated (device_id <> NULL)
2. NO, otherwise

How could I do this?

Comment: shouldn't service have contract_id or can a servoce haev multple contrcts, in that case a bridge table is the choice to join both tables

Comment: My bad. Service has contract_id

Comment: Use LEFT JOIN between the 3 tables. Then you can use `IF(device_id IS NULL, 'NO', 'YES')` to get that result.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get all records from services where (device_id <> NULL) then use them to get final results.

```
SELECT 
  c.contract_id, IF(ISNULL(s.contract_id), 'NO', 'YES')
FROM
  contracts AS c
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT contract_id FROM services WHERE NOT ISNULL(device_id)
  ) AS s ON c.contract_id = s.contract_id
```

We use `LEFT JOIN` to get all records from `contracts` table.